# Formula conditional EPPlus

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xls, epplus

I'm trying to add to my file a column with conditional formula...
But the cell stay blank or the formula show as a string.

I saw two possibilities, using _formatRangeAddress or Get each data of a cell... But my file can have 150 000+ rows...

```
 var _formatRangeAddress = new ExcelAddress("C1:Cxxxx,D1:Dxxxx"); 
        string _statement = "SI(C2=D2;Point(D2 C2);LineString(D2 C2,D3 C3)";
        var _cond4 = worksheet.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(_formatRangeAddress);
        _cond4.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        _cond4.Formula = _statement;
```

Any ideas how can I make this formula works?
Thanks.

Comment: What is SI, Point ad LineString? Are they built-in functions?